# Aplicação Java Web / Glassfish parando

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, glassfish, c3p0

Estou tendo um problema e infelizmente não estou conseguindo encontrar a causa.

Tenho 3 aplicações Java Web rodando em um servidor Glassfish e o que acontece é que essas aplicações, do nada, param de funcionar.
O Glassfish continua rodando, porém as aplicações travam.

E o pior é que não fica nenhum registro nos logs.  Simplesmente o log congela onde a aplicação parou.
Assim, infelizmente não tenho a mínima noção do que possa estar ocasionando este problema.

A aplicação é Java Web (jsp), com Hibernate, banco de dados MySQL, pool de conexão com C3P0, Glassfish 4.1.1.

Por favor, se precisarem de mais alguma informação, me informem que posto aqui.

Muito obrigado

Comment: Da um thread dump e veja qual está bloqueando..

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante, obrigado pelo retorno.  Por favor, como posso fazer o thread dump?

Comment: Recomendo o uso do Tomcat ao invés do Glassfish.